# how can i remove the last comma using python

Tags: python, loops

i have tried using this code but the comma after -63 reamins.
The problem was Write the python programs, which prints the following sequences of values in loops:18, -27, 36, -45, 54, -63

```
count = 18
while count<= 63:
   if count==-63:
      print(count)
   elif count%2 == 0:
    print(count, end=',')
   elif count%2 !=0:
     print(-1*count, end=",") 
   count+=9
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that your first `if` condition compares to `-63` which will not occur on the `count` variable (it only occurs on the print statement), to quick fix it, just change `count == -63` to `count == 63`:

```
count = 18
while count <= 63:
   if count == 63:
       print(-1*count)
   elif count%2 == 0:
       print(count, end=',')
   elif count%2 !=0:
       print(-1*count, end=",") 
   count+=9
```

outputs:
`18,-27,36,-45,54,-63`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
count = 18
output = ''
while count<= 63:
   if count==-63:
      output += (count)
   elif count%2 == 0:
    output += (str(count) + ',')
   elif count%2 !=0:
     output += (str(-1*count) + ',')
   count+=9
print(output[:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using List Comprehension:

```
print(*(i if i%2==0 else-i for i in range(18,63+1,9) ),sep=',')
```

Output:

```
18,-27,36,-45,54,-63
```